# TortoiseGit enable settings context menu

Tags: windows, context-menu, tortoise-git

My issue is that I have disabled the settings context menu so now I don't have a way to bring it back!

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a windows explorer window on a git repository
2. Right click on the repo and go
3. TortoiseGit -> Settings ...
4. Context menu 2
5. Scroll down and find "Settings" then enable it
6. Click ok

Now, the settings context menu is disappeared so there is no way to change any setting or undo this action.

How can I enable back the "Settings" context menu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: You can hold the shift key when opening the context menu to show even hidden menu entries.

Second: When you select any item in the "Context menu 2" settings page, those items will be hidden (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-look-feel-extended), so uncheck it to make it visible again.

PS: Exactly for this case there is a "Settings" entry in the TortoiseGit start menu group.